# zsh line editor: Can I navigate and edit by argument?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, line-editor

I have a common situation in the shell when a command is attempted

`command "/some/complex/and terrible/path" -vf --various --flags --and -- things --config-file="/some other/annoyingly/large/path/to/somewhere"`

and it turns out that I'm mostly there but need to move some stuff around. Suppose I have to move the last argument all the way to the front to attempt this next.

`command --config-file="/some other/annoyingly/large/path/to/somewhere" "/some/complex/and terrible/path" -vf --various --flags --and -- things`

Trying to take a keystroke golf look at this, it's a dire situation. This is actually a nightmare shell command entry scenario where you kind of have to re-type (or copy&paste) almost half the command. The best hope of sanity might be to use an external editor [[like this]](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/edit-long-commands/).

Even still, Vim isn't smart enough to do arg parsing (so there is no quick way to slurp out the last arg there using e.g. `daW`, though it should be possible to complete the job within 8 keystrokes or so given the power of vim).

I think that this can be a decent workaround, because I do bring a lot of software to bear on editing text in vim since I use it to do all of my coding.

But what I want is if Zsh (or even Bash!) line editor could be programmed somehow to let me shove an arg around. Kind of like this: https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim But of course, this plugin won't work on space delimited shell arguments either. And it requires vim.

I'd be happy with either a directional hop (so that I can put my cursor somewhere on the `--config-file` arg and then mash HopLeft to hop the arg to the left) or a yank & paste (so i can put my cursor somewhere on the `--config-file` arg, yank it out, hit home to go to the front and paste it after it).

This way we can rapidly recompose shell arguments by navigating the args as a unit rather than navigating individual characters as a unit. It would speed up general command editing a lot. I care about this a lot because I do an unusually large amount of coding directly in the shell.

If we are to take the idea further this would be implemented as an editor *mode*, let's call it Argument Edit Mode, where the cursor moves across args instead of characters and a more developed set of actions can be performed on args as a unit.

Let's come back down to earth now. The question is this: can I programmatically cause zsh to delete the shell arg that i'm currently on? And then paste it back in? Can I bind a key to let me hop based on actual args instead of just hopping words?

There doesn't seem to be ready-to-use binds for use with `bindkey`, but it feels like there might be a way to do it if i can programmatically control the position of the cursor. I do use a plugin that can live syntax highlight my command after all. https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Not quite what you're asking for, but I tend to take a word-designated command history approach to these situations. While a 'word' in ZLE is (based on my usage w/ vim keybindings, at least) simplistic and jumps between spaces, word designations in history expansion understand quotes. Your example of 'run the last command, but as `command --last-arg --all-other-args`' can be typed as `!!:0 !!:$ !!:1-`, and tab-completion will fill it in so you can verify what you're about to execute (and/or tweak with ZLE).

Comment: Yeah! That's a feature that definitely is arg-aware that i hadn't thought about leveraging, but the issues therein are related to: the mental overload of `!!:1-` (mostly remembering what `1-` means and how it works) and the fact that once I tab-complete something like `!!:-3` I can't go back and adjust it to be `!!:-2` without back-deleting it and typing it out again. Stuff like that. It is a workable thing to do, yes. But It's just not quite there from a user experience perspective.

Comment: Here is another thing that is common that is extremely impractical to use, I want to grab the third-from-last arg from the last command I ran. `!!:-3` doesnt provide me that, it actually provides me the command and first 3 args. I am having a hard time finding docs that go over this stuff and I do not know if it is possible to fetch an nth-from-last arg.   At the end of the day, the point is that my brain works by pointing a cursor at an arg to refer to it, not by scanning the entire command to count which arg i'm looking at to type it in.

Comment: Understood, that's why I didn't consider offering it as an actual answer, though I think it's worth keeping in mind as a different approach to the problem. I agree that `!!:-3` reads as though it should be third-from-last; instead that dash means 'do a range' and with no beginning index, 0 is implied. The ZLE command `undo` will, in fact, revert tab-completion. I think this is bound to `ctrl-_` in emacs bindings; I'm unsure what the vi command binding `u` points to since it sure doesn't work.

Comment: Note to self: Research the ZLE undo functionality a little bit, this will be very very useful. At the moment I use `ctrl+_` to horizontally split a pane for tmux so it will need to be rebound

Comment: I learned about `autoload copy-earlier-word && zle -N copy-earlier-word && bindkey '^[,' copy-earlier-word` it is really nice for pulling something up (in combination with `insert-last-word`), but it is unforgiving because neither `insert-last-word` nor `copy-earlier-word` are reversible. `copy-earlier-word` is supposed to cycle through, but for me, at least from testing on both linux and macOS, it does not actually cycle. Might be a bug.

Answer (score 5):

You may be looking for the `select-word-style` framework and in particular its *shell* word style. See

```
info zsh select-word-style
```

For instance, add to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
zle -N select-word-style
bindkey '\ez' select-word-style
```

Then (assuming you use the `emacs` mode)

- press <kbd>Alt+Z</kbd> to invoke `select-word-style`
- you'll get a menu where you can select the word style. Press <kbd>S</kbd> for the `shell` word style.
- then <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> will delete the previous word as a full argument (a *shell* word).
- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> or <kbd>Home</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line
- <kbd>Alt+F</kbd> to move one word to the right
- <kbd>Ctrl+Y</kbd> to yank the previously killed word.
- <kbd>Alt+Z</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> if you want to go back to the *normal* word style.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that this isn’t what I’m *looking for* per se, but this is definitely a step in the right direction, and a feature I did not know about. It does seem like maybe if this could be scripted then I could implement what I want on top of it...

Comment: This does not seem to work. The Alt+z bind appears to produce a menu that lets me choose stuff, but the ctrl+w works the same exact way whichever choice is made. zsh 5.3.1

Comment: I can not find any documentation on select-word-style.

Comment: I think the reason this doesn't work is that prezto (which I use my own fork of) sets $WORDCHARS to mimic bash's behavior, thus making the normal mode work just like bash mode for this.

Comment: If you know the documentation of this stuff, please do post it. Does "shell" mode set a different $WORDCHARS?

Comment: @StevenLu, does `info zsh select-word-style` not work for you? You may need to install a `zsh-doc` package. You'd probably not want to use that with other things that redefine the word-motion widgets. Note that `bash` is one of the word styles.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If I select `S` I still need to hit `^W` 7 times to clear the line after typing `a --b='c d'`. Is this expected?

Comment: `info zsh select-word-style` just brings up the same as `man zsh`. I did find some mention in `man zshall` at about line 17043.

Comment: @TomHale, you're probably missing the zsh documentation. If on Debian or derivative, install the `zsh-doc` package.

Comment: Cheers @StéphaneChazelas, `zsh-doc` did the trick. I got `zsh-lovers` too for good measure. Did you see my previous comment?

Comment: @TomHale, I can't reproduce. Maybe like Steven, you already use extensions that mingle with word selection. See the whole discussion above. Try with `zsh -f` to see if that works there, and then check your zshrc for things that affect the behaviour

Comment: For me, the documentation is under `man zshcontrib`.

Answer (score 3):

> The question is this: can I programmatically cause zsh to delete the shell arg that i'm currently on? And then paste it back in? Can I bind a key to let me hop based on actual args instead of just hopping words?

Yes, you can. Just use [my Zsh Edit plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit). It includes keybindings for skipping and cutting entire shell words.

Comment: Thank you for posting! Very good timing as I'm about to revisit this topic while I make a second effort to properly set up my zsh prompt; I expect this next effort will be able to last me for the next 2 decades. This looks really neat and promising. Thanks for making it so I don't have to!

Comment: Here's my entire [tag:zsh] config, if you're interested: https://github.com/marlonrichert/.config/tree/main/zsh

Comment: It's not clear to me what those two "main keymap" columns represent. Or which of those bindings *deletes the word I'm on* (which I interpret as meaning something like `vim`'s `diw` / `daw` / `diW` / `daW`).

Comment: The `main` keymap is what this always means in [tag:zsh]: whichever keymap you’ve aliased to `main`. That’s `emacs` by default, but it can be whichever keymap you want. That’s where these keybindings will be added when you source the plugin.

Comment: It does not have any bindings for deleting the word you are on. That operation is rarely used outside of `vi` or `vim`. Heck, I don’t even know what “vim's diw / daw / diW / daW” does. :)